# How can i bake multiple kinds of cheesecake at the same time in a spring-form pan?

Tags: baking, cheesecake

I'm new to baking , so i was wondering how can i bake different kinds of cheesecakes in a spring-form pan at the same time?
Example:
i want to make NY cheesecakes with three different flavors in the same pan , say one is chocolate cheesecake , one is strawberry flavored and one is peanut flavored , how should i divide the pan into three different sections so the flavors don't mix?
(I want to bake them together in the same spring-form pan)

Comment: Related, at least partially duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84824/pie-with-2-different-fillings

Comment: @Stephie well that was interesting , but i don't want to do it like that , picture that a circle is 360 degrees , i want to divide it to three 120 degree sections and fill each with a different flavor , but i want to keep them separate , and bake them at the same time in the same pan , as i don't have enough ingredients to make 3 separate ones , and if i want to make 3 separate ones with the amount of ingredient  i have , it would become too thin.

Comment: I suppose you saw the answer that suggests a strip of folded aluminum foil? Think “straight” instead of “circle” (the asker there explicitly wanted rings).

Comment: @Stephie yeah didn't see that , why don't you add the answer then instead of commenting it? although i should try it first i guess it would work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start separating your pie, you need to be sure that your fillings all need the same baking time and temperature. If they are from the same basic recipe and just have some extra flavors, you should be ok, if they are smaller amounts of different recipes, check the instructions carefully or ideally, make them as full pies once and note the actual parameters - random recipes from the Internet can be quite different, not all bloggers use an oven thermometer etc.

But assuming that this is taken care of, you simply need something that has the right length (radius of your pie tin), is food safe, heat proof, and water resistant. For similar problems I have used:

- Aluminum strips (fold a few times to get some stability)
- Cardboard strips wrapped tightly in aluminum foil or baking parchment.
- A pie divider (a special gadget that goes into a regular pan, separating it, similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00576ARAA) pie pan, comes also in [square](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alan-Silverwood-Extra-Dividers-Multisize/dp/B000GW89M8?th=1&psc=1)).
- Glass cut to match the shape of the tin - although that was a loaf tin.

Once you have the tool of your choice, the real challenge is to keep them upright during filling and getting the tin into the oven. A kitchen helper is highly recommended.